# UIImagePickerViewController(performing action automaticcaly when maxduration set for video is reached)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am stuck with an issue,I have set `VideoMaxDuration` to 10 seconds,I want to perform an action as soon as `maxduration` is reached,How will I be able to check that,suggest something as I have already referred to the apple docs as well as stackoverflow's previous questions but haven't found any solution yet.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far

Comment: After taking object for UIImagePickerViewController I have set the max duration as under:-
imgPicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;
now the thing is I haven't found any solution to perform any task automatically  when max duration is reached.

Comment: Its so important for me.. and I haven't got reply from you guys yet.. Waiting..

Comment: Can you show the full code you are using when you create the UIIamgePickerController

Comment: imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imgPicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    imgPicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    [imgPicker setShowsCameraControls:NO];
    imgPicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;
    
    [self.view addSubview:imgPicker.view];

Comment: no solution??? havent found any yet.